# Trying to understand the output of model.predict

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to predict the cat/dog image using the model.predict method. Since it is 2 class classifier I am getting an array of 2 values. As per my understanding, these values represent the probabilities to belong in each class (correct me if I am wrong). If it is so the probability must be summed to 1. But I am getting the same probability for both classes

Model History

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
flatten (Flatten)            multiple                  0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                multiple                  30848     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            multiple                  0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization (BatchNo multiple                  512       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              multiple                  12900     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          multiple                  0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (Batch multiple                  400       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              multiple                  10100     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          multiple                  0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_2 (Batch multiple                  400       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              multiple                  10100     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)          multiple                  0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_3 (Batch multiple                  400       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              multiple                  10100     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_4 (Dropout)          multiple                  0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_4 (Batch multiple                  400       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_5 (Dense)              multiple                  202       
=================================================================
Total params: 76,362
Trainable params: 75,306
Non-trainable params: 1,056
```

---

Prediction Code

```
class_prob=model.predict(new_array_2.T,batch_size=1)
print(class_prob)
classifications=model.predict_classes(new_array_2.T,batch_size=1)
print(classifications)
print(CATEGORIES[classifications[0]])
```

output

```
[[0.39456758 0.39456758]]
[0]
Dog
```

Comment: Please add your model code, what is the activation of the last layer?

Comment: Can we see the model code and/or summary?

Comment: @Stewart_R The summary is right there in the question.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro haha - my bad. Indeed it is, sorry! I was expecting to see a summary with explicit output shapes and guess I just ignored it all. My comment "crossed" with yours else I would have never bothered. If I'd have spotted my folly before you did I'd have just deleted it. Alas now, having had to apologise and explain why I was such a donkey, I daren't delete it so my donkeyness will remain for all to see for all eternity! :-) Nevermind!

Answer (score 1):

`model.predict` just returns the computed output of your model given the input, so all the details you mentioned depend on the model's output, for example, activations at the last layer.

That the model outputs probabilities that sum to one is only produced by the `softmax` activation at the output layer, to me it looks like your last layer has a different activation, probably `sigmoid`, which will not produce probabilities that sum to one. You should prefer to use `softmax` for multi-class classification.

Comment: You are right I am using sigmoid activation function. But I want to understand if the out is not probability than what it is and why I am getting equal value for both classes.                    Anyway tried softmax during initial run didn't get good accuracy (train/test) that's the reason I switched to sigmoid. I will try again with softmax and will let you know if I observe any difference

Comment: I have tried with softmax(poor accuracy) and with sigmoid                                                                   ```                                                                                                                                          -----------softmax-------------
Epoch 205/205
18709/18709 [==============================] - 4s 233us/sample - loss: 0.2500 - accuracy: 0.5528
-----sigmoid-------------
Epoch 205/205
18709/18709 [==============================] - 5s 246us/sample - loss: 0.2383 - accuracy: 0.9247